# Regular expression pattern to find a word in the delimited multiline string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want the output as **Test_guest1613** if the pattern is for Guest Name and **AK004** if the pattern is for Room Number

```
let mystring = `The description value is Holrest
Code: adip-345

Guest Name : Test_guest1613 
Room Number: AK004 
Request Number : 107157
Request Method: Email
Dates Requested:25-Jul-2020 08:00PM
If no specific date, weekday or weekend : N/A 
Start Time:25-Jul-2020 08:00PM
Time Zone : ET `;

re=/Guest Name\s?:\s?(.*?)( |$)/g;

mystring.match(re);
```

gives me the array output Guest Name : Test_guest1613 but i want just want Test_guest1613

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.exec(mystring)` to collect captured groups and access the second in the array.

```js
let mystring = `The description value is Holrest
Code: adip-345

Guest Name : Test_guest1613 
Room Number: AK004 
Request Number : 107157
Request Method: Email
Dates Requested:25-Jul-2020 08:00PM
If no specific date, weekday or weekend : N/A 
Start Time:25-Jul-2020 08:00PM
Time Zone : ET `;

re=/Code\s?:\s?(.*?)(?:\n| |$)+Guest Name\s?:\s?(.*?)(?: |$)/gm;

let matches = re.exec(mystring);

let code = matches[1];
let guestName = matches[2];


console.log(guestName, code);
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer @Ahmad, but this code is not working for me to fetch Code value which is adip-345. Could you please help with this.

Comment: @Girish I updated my answer to include code with guestname. check my snippet above

Answer (score 0):

You could remove `Guest Name :` after the fact with `.replace`.
I.E.: `mystring.match(re).replace(/Guest Name\s?:\s?/)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want both values for `Guest Name` and `Room Number`, you could use 2 capturing groups:

```
^Guest Name\s?:\s?(.*?)\s*\r?\nRoom Number\s?:\s?(.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nhnvh2/1)

These are the separate pattern, for which you could use group 1 to get the value

`^Guest Name\s?:\s?(.*?)[^\S\r\n]*$` and `^Room Number\s?:\s?(.*?)[^\S\r\n]*$`

```js
const regex = /^Guest Name\s?:\s?(.*?)\s*\r?\nRoom Number\s?:\s?(.*)/m;
const str = `The description value is Holrest
Code: adip-345

Guest Name : Test_guest1613 
Room Number: AK004 
Request Number : 107157
Request Method: Email
Dates Requested:25-Jul-2020 08:00PM
If no specific date, weekday or weekend : N/A 
Start Time:25-Jul-2020 08:00PM
Time Zone : ET `;

let m = str.match(regex);
console.log(m[1]);
console.log(m[2]);
```